# Default props are not available in redux's mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component for which I've set some `defaultProps`. When I'm making a redux action dispatch I want that `defaultProp` to be used. But unfortunately, I'm getting that prop as `undefined`. Is there any way that I can access the `defaultProps` without checking the `undefined` condition.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
      console.log(this.props.myProp); // is not giving undefined
   }
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = { myProp: 'Hello World!' };

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        myAction: () => dispatch(action(ownProps.myProp)) // Here myProp is undefined
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponet);
```

Comment: thats how its supposed to be. `ownProps` has only those props which are passed explicitly to HOC, ie. the connected `MyComponent`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I do understand that is the implementation of the `connect` HOC. Is there any documentation that says `defaultProps` aren't available in `ownProps`? I found nothing. I guess this has to be added to the issues list.

Comment: The [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#ownprops-1) clearly states that  the props passed to the wrapper component is the second parameter. You never pass `myProp` to the wrapper so it's not available in `ownProps`. If you are not happy with this behaviour you can open an issue on github to discuss it. Maybe they will add it, but I don't see any use of it.